# Do we want questions about the relationships between Latin and other languages to be on- or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

As a more general version of [this question](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20/21), do we want the relationships between Latin and other languages (both preceding and following) to be on-topic?

I'd answer *yes* to both.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd definitely answer yes to the relationship to languages *preceding*. The relationship between Latin and any other preceding language is, almost by definition, significantly related to Latin.

The relationship between Latin and *following* languages is a little fuzzier. We wouldn't want questions that are *really* about English words which happen to have Latin roots. I would be comfortable allowing questions about the etymology of words, at least to start.

If it becomes a problem, we can shut them down.